# Roslyn Visual Studio 2017, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis Version 2.6.1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, roslyn, code-analysis

We are programming a Roslyn Visual Studio 2017 plugin on the platform Microsoft.CodeAnalysis 2.6.1.

- Actual state:

  We created a VSIX project and programmed some simple **DiagnosticAnalyzer** subclasses, which were loaded correctly after adding the assets to the **source.extension.vsixmanifest** file (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943167.aspx).
- Current state:
  Our plugin should also be able to do some simple refactorings. So we created a subclass of **CodeFixProvider**.
  Unfortunately the hook methods of the CodeFixProvider never gets called. Does somebody know why?

Thats my code:

```
[ExportCodeFixProvider(LanguageNames.CSharp), Shared]
    public sealed class BooleanComparisonCodeFixProvider : CodeFixProvider
    {
        public override ImmutableArray FixableDiagnosticIds {
              get { // never gets called }
        }

        public override Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
        {
             // never gets called
        }

        public sealed override FixAllProvider GetFixAllProvider()
        {
             // never gets called
        }
    }
```

Greets MjeOsX

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `[ExportCodeFixProvider(LanguageNames.Whatever)]` to export your class to Visual Studio's MEF container.

Comment: I did this already but this didn't work. Thank you.
I added the code in the question section.

Comment: Did you set your VSIX to deploy your project as MEF? Do other MEF exports work? Check Debug, Modules to see if you've loaded multiple versions of Roslyn.